# How are sheaves/stacks viewed as generalised spaces?

Tags: homotopy-theory, sheaf-theory, higher-category-theory, algebraic-stacks

Whenever I read literature that deals with higher categories, there is a point of view that sheaves/stacks are generalised spaces. What does that mean?

For me, a space is a place to draw things. A CW complex or a simplicial set is an acceptable space for me. Since I accept a simplicial set as a space, I can imagine groupoids as spaces.

If a sheaf/stack is a generalised space, then how do I "specialise" a sheaf/stack to a topological space or a sSet? How do I draw stuff in a sheaf/stack?

Comment: You can draw a circle on a plane because you have morphisms $S^1\to\mathbb{R}^2$, you can draw a line because you have morphisms $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ and more generally you can draw various stuff because, you have morphisms $X\to\mathbb{R}^2$. This shows that the object $Hom(.,\mathbb{R}^2)$ is relevant here, and it turns out that it has two important properties : it is a sheaf on $Top$ (which is representable) and this sheaf completely characterizes $\mathbb{R}^2$ (Yoneda lemma). Remove the condition that the sheaf is representable and you have a generalization of a space.

Comment: So to answer the question how to draw a circle on a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $Top$, simply take an element $\mathcal{F}(S^1)$. By Yoneda, this is the same thing as taking a morphism $S^1\to\mathcal{F}$ (where $S^1$ denotes here the sheaf represented by $S^1$).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the sheaf represented by ¹". Is this ( . , ¹ )?